# Unexpected end of stream at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream

Tags: asp.net-core

```
System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of stream.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.<ReadAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.<DrainAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReader.<ReadNextSectionAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at AspNetCoreFileUpload.Controllers.FileUploadController.<Index>d__0.MoveNext() 
in C:\\GitHub\\StackOverflow\\LargeFileUploadController\\FileUploadController.cs:line 29
```

Repro: https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow/tree/master/LargeFileUploadController

Form

```
<form action = ""/FileUpload"" method=""post"" enctype=""multipart/form-data"">
    <label for=""myfile1"">File</label>
    <input type=""file"" name=""myFile1"" />
    <label for=""myfile2"">File</label>
    <input type=""file"" name=""myFile2"" />
    <input type=""submit"" value=""Send"" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
public class FileUploadController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var boundary = GetBoundary(Request.ContentType);
        var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, Request.Body);

        try
        {
            var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(new { ex = ex.ToString() });
        }

        return new OkObjectResult(new { message = "Done" });
    }

    private static string GetBoundary(string contentType)
    {
        var elements = contentType.Split(' ');
        var element = elements.Where(entry => entry.StartsWith("boundary=")).First();
        var boundary = element.Substring("boundary=".Length);
        // Remove quotes
        if (boundary.Length >= 2 && 
            boundary[0] == '"' && boundary[boundary.Length - 1] == '"')
        {
            boundary = boundary.Substring(1, boundary.Length - 2);
        }
        return boundary;
    }
}
```

Comment: This usually means you have the boundary wrong. Step through GetBoundary and make sure it's working correctly. There's also Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue that can parse this for you.

Answer (score 11):

I got *almost* the same exception recently. I'm saying *almost* because they actually renamed the exception to `Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.`, which actually means that something already consumed the body stream. The comments of the following change gives us the understanding of what's happening:

> [Tratcher commented on Mar 23](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/commit/ce408a999ea271f8b2083cf5019226a99f00fd0c#commitcomment-16808912)
>
> > ...The MVC model binder reads the form and buffers the multipart segments
> >     for you, so there's no point in re-parsing request body with the
> >     MultipartReader...

So, the question is how to disable the default form binding (reading the request form)?

I found the `DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute` attribute in this [Mvc.FileUpload sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.FileUpload)  which disables the form binding and this is what it looks like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        var formValueProviderFactory = context.ValueProviderFactories
                .OfType<FormValueProviderFactory>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
        if (formValueProviderFactory != null)
        {
            context.ValueProviderFactories.Remove(formValueProviderFactory);
        }

        var jqueryFormValueProviderFactory = context.ValueProviderFactories
            .OfType<JQueryFormValueProviderFactory>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (jqueryFormValueProviderFactory != null)
        {
            context.ValueProviderFactories.Remove(jqueryFormValueProviderFactory);
        }
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

If you want some more information, you can check out the following:

- [Create a filter/sample that shows how to remove the form value providers (rynowak opened this issue on Apr 26)](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4534)
- [Sample: Issues with Antiforgery + Form + File Uploads (rynowak opened this issue on Apr 26)](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4533)

Just for info - as commented before, *the MVC model binder reads the form*, but where can one find the results. The results can be found in the `HttpRequest.Form`, which has `Files`.

Answer (score 8):

Don't know if this might help you but I came across simular issue "Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component".

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            context.Request.EnableRewind();
            await next();
        });
```

Code above were added in Startup.cs Configure method.

Hope it helps

Comment: Came across the same issue and this solved it! But i'd really like to know why and how it solves it. anyone?

Comment: Is there an updated solutioin for ASPNET Core 3.0? I tried this, but Request doesn't have a definition of EnableRewind, and there are no suggestions for imports/assemblies. I have tried context.Request.EnableBuffering(), but this either doesn't help (if I put it at the end of Configure method) or causes all requests to return 500 Internal Server error (when I put it at the beginning).

Comment: @Shaggydog
I got it to compile by changing to "EnableBuffering", but I still get the same exception.


    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

    app.Use(async (context, next) => {
        context.Request.EnableBuffering();
        await next();
    });

Comment: @programmerj yes, I figured that one out. However putting this in the Startup.cs Configure method caused problems. In the end I managed to make it work by creating a custom attribute public class EnableBufferingAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter {public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
        }

Comment: @Shaggydog Your code worked for me, you should have posted it as an answer so its easier to spot. Thanks!

Comment: @Shaggydog write that as an answer. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I created a MemoryStream, copied stream from body there and it was working like a charm :) Point is you cannot read Stream twice. However, this is not a case for MemoryStream. Of course, you have to be sure about scaling, I don't think this will work for really big files uploaded. I didn't tested this.
I rewrote example from Microsoft site: [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
Here is part of it:

```
    while (section != null)
{
    ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition;
    var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition, out contentDisposition);

    if (hasContentDispositionHeader)
    {
        if (MultipartRequestHelper.HasFileContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var fileSection = section.AsFileSection();
            await fileSection.FileStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            documentUpload.Attachments.Add(new SimpleFileInstance { FileName = fileSection.FileName, FileStream = ms });

        }
        else if (MultipartRequestHelper.HasFormDataContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
        {
            // Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"//
            // value
            // Do not limit the key name length here because the 
            // multipart headers length limit is already in effect.
            var key = HeaderUtilities.RemoveQuotes(contentDisposition.Name).Value;
            var encoding = GetEncoding(section);
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(
                section.Body,
                encoding,
                detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true,
                bufferSize: 1024,
                leaveOpen: true))
            {
                // The value length limit is enforced by MultipartBodyLengthLimit
                var value = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

                if (string.Equals(value, "undefined", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    value = string.Empty;
                }

                formAccumulator.Append(key, value);

                if (formAccumulator.ValueCount > DefaultFormOptions.ValueCountLimit)
                {
                    throw new InvalidDataException($"Form key count limit {DefaultFormOptions.ValueCountLimit} exceeded.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
}
```

**documentUpload** is our DTO to work further with files. In our case, some documents gets uploaded to SharePoint.