# Disabling Model Binding for Post Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement the file streaming example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads

As part of that, I have implemented the filter:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        var formValueProviderFactory = context.ValueProviderFactories
            .OfType<FormValueProviderFactory>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (formValueProviderFactory != null)
        {
            context.ValueProviderFactories.Remove(formValueProviderFactory);
        }

        var jqueryFormValueProviderFactory = context.ValueProviderFactories
            .OfType<JQueryFormValueProviderFactory>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (jqueryFormValueProviderFactory != null)
        {
            context.ValueProviderFactories
                .Remove(jqueryFormValueProviderFactory);
        }
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

I am getting an IOException

```
System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have 
already been read by another component. 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.
<ReadAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
```

This is... vexing.  I've found this question 
[Unexpected end of stream at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444457/unexpected-end-of-stream-at-microsoft-aspnetcore-webutilities-multipartreaderstr)

To which the answer is basically "Implement the DisableFormValueModelBinding Attribute".  Obviously, that isn't working.

My Razor code is

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="FileStore" asp-action="LargeUpload">
    <div class="form-group">
        <!--<div class="col-md-10">
            <p>Please describe your file</p>
            <input type="text" name="description"/>
        </div>-->
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
            <input type="file" name="files" multiple/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Large Upload" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my Controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> LargeUpload()
{
    if (!MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
    {
        return BadRequest($"Expected a multipart request, but got {Request.ContentType}");
    }

    //// Used to accumulate all the form url encoded key value pairs in the 
    //// request.
    //var formAccumulator = new KeyValueAccumulator();
    //string targetFilePath = null;

    var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
        MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType),
        _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
    var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);

    var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
}
```

Does anyone know if I've missed something or if the tutorials are out of date?
I'm running VS2017 community with ASP.NET Core 1.1.2

Comment: I just implemented this yesterday using ASP.NET Core 2.0.0 preview1-final successfully, maybe try that and see if you still have the same issue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I managed to work around it, but I'm going to try that now.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you got it working? (Post an answer)

Comment: I worked around it by doing something completely different - it was context dependent and wouldn't help anyone else, I just changed the user journey. Sorry I can't be more help.